# Good reference for all useful data annotations for Entity Framework (6+) models?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I have been unable to find a good reference for all useful data annotations that can be used on Entity Framework code-first models. I've found a [Code First Data Annotations article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx) and the [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Namespace reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) and the [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reference but there are a few that can be used from the System.ComponentModel namespace (i.e. the commonly used DisplayName annotation) for your data model, but not all of them.

Is there a better reference for what is and is not useful for EF data model annotations? I think part of the answer also involves which annotations are actually used today by the default EF templates. I just wrote my own little extension that gets the Display(Description) annoations so I can use that in my HTML title tags (and thus by handy things like jQueryUI's tooltips) so I suppose it's possible to "use" a ton of annotations if you extract them yourself. But there are many used by EF to figure out your model schema, too. It's just really aggravating to bounce back and forth between the various references figuring out which annotations you can pick from. I should just quit whining and publish my own little cheat sheet huh :) But in the interests of DRY I'm hoping that already exists somewhere!

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no complete and updated  reference for Last version of EF which cover all aspects of the Code first approach.You have to involve in couple of things such as text book on this issue or videos,but the best way I recommend you to do is,to decompile resources or assemblies in Visual studio and Resharper tools and try to figure out by codes.

**Update**:EF Code First Data Annotations are limited by count(about 16) and if you want to have more control over your Data Model creating you have to use EF  [Code First Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx) way to do it.Here are some good references:

["Configuring/Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

["Entity Framework Tutorial"](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx)